# dropdownlistfor Hierarchy razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, hierarchy, dropdownlistfor

I am sure this should be pretty easy. But i cannot get it to work trying myself and googling for a day :-(

The table I use is the following (see below). This contains a field ST_ID and a field ST_BELONGSTO. Tis is actually storing the hierarchy i am looking for. So if a row has a value other then zero in the field ST_belongsto that means is it is sub-category of the topone.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDropdown](
    [ST_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ST_CODE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ST_DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ST_VALUE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ST_ACTIVE] [bit] NULL,
    [ST_BELONGSTO] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDropdown] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ST_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I fill my dropdown in the view through the controler with

```
ViewBag.ST_BELONGSTO = new SelectList(db.tblDropdown.Where(p => p.ST_CODE == "AR_GROUP1" && (p.IS_COMPANY == 0 || p.IS_COMPANY == i && p.ST_ACTIVE == true)), "ST_ID", "ST_DESCRIPTION");
```

this works fine. It shows al records. What is the problem you think :-). I would like to achive a dropdown with hierarchy so it does not show just a list of values but for example

```
Categorie 1
   -->Subcat 2
   -->Subcat 5
 Categorie2
   -->Subcat 8
   -->Subcat 7
```

etc...

I have found the OPTGROUP but that is not workable because the groups have selectable ID's as well.

I have tried linq query below as well, but this shows me only the records which have subrecords. And does not show the subrecords.

```
 var topics = db.tblDropdown;
                var types = db.tblDropdown;
                var query = from topic in topics
                            join type in types on topic.ST_ID equals type.ST_BELONGSTO
                            select new { Group = type.ST_ID, ID = topic.ST_ID, Description = topic.ST_DESCRIPTION };

                ViewBag.ST_BELONGSTO = new SelectList(query, "ID", "Description", "Group");
```

In the view the dropdown is looking like

```
<div class="list-left">
    @SeaFuy.ResourceProviders.LocalizationResourceProvider.Current.GetString("RE_TYPE1")
</div>
<div class="list-right">
@Html.DropDownList("ST_BELONGSTO", String.Empty) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST_BELONGSTO)
</div>
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Best regards, Marcel